# Program to calculate homology of a Koszul complex involving univariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sagemath, magma

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_6]$ be a polynomial ring. Then we may form the Koszul complex $K(x_1,...,x_6)$ which looks something like:

$$ R \xrightarrow{d_6} R^6 \xrightarrow{d_5} R^{15} \xrightarrow{} ... \xrightarrow{d_2} R^6 \xrightarrow{d_1} R $$

where, for example, $$d_1 = (x_1,x_2,...,x_6)$$

$$d_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -x_2 &-x_3 &-x_4 &-x_5 &-x_6 &  0 &0&   0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\       
  x_1  & 0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &-x_3 &-x_4& -x_5& -x_6&   0&   0&   0 &  0 &  0&  0\\      
   0 & x_1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & x_2 &  0 &  0 &  0& -x_4& -x_5& -x_6 &  0 &  0 &  0\\     
   0   &0&  x_1&   0 &  0 &  0 & x_2 &  0 &  0 & x_3 &  0 &  0 &-x_5 &-x_6 &  0\\      
   0  & 0  & 0 & x_1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & x_2 &  0 &  0 & x_3 &  0 & x_4 &0 &-x_6\\      
   0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & x_1 &  0 &  0  & 0 & x_2 &  0 &  0 & x_3 &  0 & x_4 & x_5\\  \end{pmatrix}$$

etc. Now, each of the $x_i$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ (what is happening here is that the $x_i$ are characters of a group, and in writing them as polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ we are restricting the characters, but this is not so important).

So let's say for example we have:

$$x_1 = (t-2)(t^2 + 1)$$
$$x_2 = (t-2)(t+2)(t^3 + 4t + 8)$$
$$\dots$$

then by tensoring above complex with $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ (i.e. $- \otimes_R \mathbb{Z}[t]$) we form what I am calling the Koszul complex in one variable:

$$ \mathbb{Z}[t] \xrightarrow{d_6} \mathbb{Z}[t]^6 \xrightarrow{d_5} \mathbb{Z}[t]^{15} \xrightarrow{} ... \mathbb{Z}[t]^6 \xrightarrow{d_1} \mathbb{Z}[t] $$

where the $d_i$ are just the $d_i$ above, but each of the $x_i$ are replaced with their expression/restriction in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

I have found that sagemath has a KoszulComplex function which gives the Koszul complex in terms of the $x_i$, but I don't believe there any any implement for using this to compute homology groups.

I cannot seem to find a prebuilt way to compute the homology groups here, although it seems like this should exist. Finally, I will add that if Euclidean-domainness is an issue, I am happy to replace $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ with $F[t]$ where $F = \mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any implementations of "homology of a chain complex" over any ring except $R = k$ a field or $R = \Bbb Z$, and the latter is much less developed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @user1079171, Thanks - unfortunately this is also the conclusion I was getting from my online searches. Perhaps I can do it by hand in the cases I'm interested in!